# How to write a json file log, into a html table

Tags: php, html, json, file

Here my first question in SO:

I have a simple log.json where are wrote some messages like:

```
{"name":"Bob","message":"Hey there"}{"name":"Alice","message":"Hi Sir"}
```

So, what I would is to read the content of log.json and put it in a simple html table,

I did like this:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if ($_SESSION['me'] == "") {    // Just in case you got a session
            header("location:index.php");
        }

        $logFile = "log.json";
        $data = file_get_contents($logFile);
        $json_data = json_decode($data);
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Message History</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    User
                </td>
                <td>
                    Messages
                </td>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach ($json_data as $row) { 
                ?>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?= $row->name; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?= $row->message; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php
                }           // close my loop
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Back Home" onclick="location.href='home.php';">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Of course doesn't work.. any idea or advise?
Thank you guys!

Edit:
Here is how i write json in log.json:

```
$logFile = "log.json";
            $file = json_encode(array('name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message));   
            file_put_contents($logFile, $file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: What errors are u getting

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a bunch of JSON texts concatenated together. I wouldn't like to try to detangle it (although you might have some luck if you keep pulling tokens off it and trying to parse them until you get a match and then looping)

Comment: I got an empty table and no error on console.

Comment: You get an empty table since `json_decode()` fails and return false

Comment: Your appending data in log.json file which make it invalid json, so instead of appending override json file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON in your log file is not valid, because a wrapping array and the comma separators are missing between the items. You have to rewrite your write function. Take a look at this quick example:

```
<?php

$logFile = "log.json";
$content = array('name'=> "Max", 'message'=> "Test 123");
$existing = json_decode(@file_get_contents($logFile));
if(!$existing || !is_array($existing))
{
    $existing = array();
}
$existing = array_merge($existing, array($content));
file_put_contents($logFile, json_encode($existing), LOCK_EX);
```

This should work.

Comment: Well, what I needed was a better json file, and add "true" in json_decode.